# disagreement between recursion tree method and master theorem

Tags: algorithm

My solution:

[image]

I am trying to find running time of T(n) = T(n/2) + T(n/4) + Θ(n) but I have different answers using recursion tree and master theorem. Was I wrong from the recursion tree diagram part or did I use wrong asymptotic notation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the master theorem (not match to any cases). You should use the [Akra-Bazzi theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method) (a general case of the master theorem).

Comment: Just for clarification, we cannot use master theorem when we have more than one dividend in the subproblems?